# Solenoid field calculations

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I have been looking for a day or so now, into the field of solenoids (no pun intended). I had the problem of trying to lift a weight between two parallel solenoids attracting (/being attracted by) a metal surface above them. I've found out about magnetic flux density, and how to calculated that from the voltage and current, as well as the formula to calculate the force on the solenoid's axis - but nothing on how do calculate it on points away from the axis.

Basically, I need to know how to calculate the force between two parallel solenoids - not one each other's axes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A solenoid generates a magnetic field; it won't lift 'a weight' unless the weight is a magnet or magnetizable.  The geometry and materials matter, so describe them...

Comment: Sorry for the extreme delay in replying: The weight is attached to the solenoid, and is being lifted by the magnetic field generated between the solenoid and the metal surface above it. The material I don't know precisely, but assuming that I would be able to find the magnetic permeability of the material, and substitute it in, we could say for the sake of argument here, that it's pure iron (unless there's a factor I've forgotten - pretty likely!)